# How to store key and value in PHP Associative Array?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a PHP Code

```
$brandNames = array();
foreach ($maufacturers as $manu) {
    array_push($brandNames, array($manu->getTitle() => $manu->getUrl()));
}
print_r($brandNames);
```

I am getting output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key0] => val0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => val1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key2] => val2
        )
)
```

I need output as

```
Array
(
     [key0] => val0
     [key1] => val1
     [key2] => val2
     [key3] => val3
)
```

Not the nested array 
Just all keys and values inside one wrapper array.

Comment: foreach ($maufacturers as $key => $manu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$brandNames = array();
foreach ($maufacturers as $manu) {
    $brandNames[$manu->getTitle()] = $manu->getUrl();
}
print_r($brandNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$brandNames = array();
foreach ($maufacturers as $key => $manu) {
    $brandNames[$manu->getTitle()] = $manu->getUrl();
}
print_r($brandNames);
```